# Regex just broke on Bluehost

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

This is my error which seems related to a server upgrade.

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class 

// The regex that did not compile
return preg_match("/^[\.\pL-0-9'\s]+$/u", $value);
```

I cannot see the issue and have not found clear documentation on which chars now may need to be escaped.

```
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 10.32 2018-09-10
PCRE Unicode Version => 11.0.0

php 7.3.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a range with unicode properties, the error comes from the hyphen between `\pL` and `0`. Some implementations of PCRE accept it as a hyphen some other don't.

Just remove it or, if you want to match hyphen, escape it or put it at the beginning or at the end of the character class:

```
[.\pL0-9'\s]
```

or

```
[.\pL\-0-9'\s]
```

or

```
[-.\pL0-9'\s]
```

or

```
[.\pL0-9'\s-]
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess (and yep, confirmed in 7.3.11) is that it's the `L-0-9` part that's failing.

Is the first hyphen meant to be treated as a literal hyphen? If so, escape it.

If not, what are you trying to match?